# Get content from another site with no limit

Tags: php, get

I have permission to use the table with a link to its inclusion on its website, where the name will be redirected to the landing page. However, the website owner is not able to say whether and how to modify the address of the page to display all the records in the table at once without paging.

It is even possible? If so, what you need to use GET?

http://www.newconnect.pl/?page=1045&id_firm=&id_tr=&ncc_index=ESC&ph_main_content_order=&ph_main_content_order_type=&ph_main_content_offset=0

Currently on one page displays only 20 records.

Comment: They have RSS ... have you investigated that option?

Comment: Yes, they have RSS, but only news... The site currently refers to a file tickerxml.php, which lets JS
var so = new SWFObject ("marque.swf", "ticker", "990", "32", "7", "# eeece7");
so.addParam ("wmode", "transparent");
so.addVariable ("url", "tickerxml.php");
so.addVariable ("space", "80");
so.addVariable ("ticketurl", "% 3Fpage 3Dznajdz_spolke%%% 26ph_main_content_start 3Dshow% 26ncc_index% 3d");
so.write ("ticker");

Answer (score 1):

First of all ask site owner if it has some API to share data. It would be much easier.

If not you always can write a crawler and move from page to page, to get data. I strongly recommend to use [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) to get website content.

Comment: I'm using WP Crawler, and I get content, but only first page, and I wanna to get all pages in one page. All pages I mean all records from table. Owner can't get me database access.

Comment: Use paging (<td class="TabARight">) as source of links to rest of pages. Crawl from page to page geting data from table.

Comment: Yes, but it gives me only the first 20 records

Comment: In paging you have link to next page. Crawl through next page to last one getting 20 records per page. You can also just add 20 to ph_main_content_offset param from link to get next page.

Comment: Thanks for answers, but this currently I know. I wanna change limit in the first page to get all of content in one table, not with pagination. Can u write on my email? jakub @ jozwiak edu pl

Comment: As far as I can see there is no such option.